# How to use a variable for a path with an astertik "*" in bash?

Tags: bash, variables, path

I have a problem with variable that's content is a path with an asterisk.

example:

- ./script
- /config
- /export
- /home/*

```
#!/bin/bash
#
dir=()
for i in $@; do
dir+="$i"
done
```

This variable comes from user input when starting the script.
But as soon as I use this variable, bash expands `/home/*` to all folders under `/home`.

I want to check the variable with a test statement and if there is an asterisk then run a command.

```
for i in ${dir[*]}; do
  if [[ "$i" == *"*"* ]]; then find $i -maxdepth 1 -type d
  fi
done
```

Do you have any idea how to do it right, or maybe a suggestion how to avoid this with a different way to get it done???

Comment: Not sure I understand your question.  If you invoke your script as `./script /config /export /home/*`, then your script will never see the `*`.  The shell that invokes that script will expand the glob and pass the expanded values to the script.

Comment: If you do `a="/home/*"` followed by `./script /config /export $a`, the same thing happens.  If you do `./script /config /export "$a"`, the script gets only 3 arguments, one of which contains `*`.  More context is needed.

Comment: If you just escape it does it work the way you expect (`/home/\*`)

Comment: You also need to double-quote several parameter and variable references to prevent wildcard expansion, e.g. `for i in $@` should use `"$@"`. And you're appending to the array wrong. [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) will point these problems out.

Comment: If you quote the asterisk on the command line it will pass in the asterisk - then it depends on whether you quote it in the script.  `dir+="$i"` would just make it part of the path name, quoted. Speaking of which - `for i in $@; do; dir+="$i"; done` is just a hard way to say `dir=( $@ )`, though in either, if you don't quote `"$@"`, path names with embedded spaces will break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most variable expansions (with very few exceptions) should be in double-quotes. Then you can handle (almost) arbitrary arguments. Two random examples:

```sh
check_asterisk_v1() {
  local a
  for a in "$@"; do
    [[ "$a" == *'*'* ]] &&
        echo "argument '${a}' contains an asterisk"
  done
  echo "${#} arguments in total"
}

check_asterisk_v2() {
  local -ar args=("$@")
  local -i i
  for i in "${!args[@]}"; do
    [[ "${args[i]}" == *'*'* ]] &&
        echo "$((i + 1)). argument '${args[i]}' contains an asterisk"
  done
  echo "${#args[@]} arguments in total"
}

check_asterisk_v1 a '*' b '**' c '***' d
check_asterisk_v2 a '*' b '**' c '***' d
```

As a side note, let me point out that your for-cycle looks wrong. This appends strings to the first element (index `0`) of array `dir` (which does not make much sense):

```sh
dir=()
for i in "$@"; do dir+="$i"; done
```

This appends elements to the array `dir` (which you may have actually intended to do):

```sh
dir=()
for i in "$@"; do dir+=("$i"); done
```

This is an easier way to achieve the same result:

```sh
dir=("$@")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot to all of you... you helped not only solving my problem, but to understand it too...

best regards...